# javascript timer to show how much passed since certain time

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(24, 0, 0); 

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { 
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('last').innerHTML =
      hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
```

I have a code which counts how much time left till certain time. But I need to reverse it and make it show how much time has passed since certain time.

Comment: So, just switch `start` and `now` in your calculations?

Comment: (Consider using [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)?)

Comment: Just stating your goal and waiting for others to write the code for you is frowned upon in this community. Is there something specific you don't understand and need help with? Is there something you tried that gave you unexpected results?

Comment: I'm total newbie in programming, I just found this code online and would be grateful if someone could provide me edited code and explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are talking about the future therefore `now > start`.
Also if now's `hh` is less than start's `hh` we should decrement the start's `hh`.
So the code would be as follows:

```js
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(24, 0, 0); // 11pm

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now < start) {
      start.setDate(start.getDate() - 1);
    }
    var remain = ((now - start) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    var diff = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    console.clear();
    console.log(diff);
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
  tick()
})();
```

Comment: Hey! I have updated your answer to add a live demo of your code. You may consider adding `console.clear();` just before your `console.log();` in the `tick` function in order for the console to be cleared and to have a better UX when seeing your answer. I may add that myself if you'd allow me to. Thanks. BTW, clearing the console **HAS NOTHING** to do with resolving the OP's issue it's only about users UX here on SO.

Comment: Hey @ths thanks for the contribution. I did as you suggested.